# how to get random json data and append to div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Say this is my json

```
[
{
    "imageSmall": ["images/employee_jpgs/employees_abhishek_80x80.jpg"],
    "imageBig": ["images/employee_jpgs/employees_abhishek_150x150.jpg"],
    "name": ["Abhishek Shet"],
    "quotes": ["Just perfect to start your career after school. Makes me feel        others in the industry are way slower then us. Awesome team and and a brilliant product to work on!!!!. And most importantly I enjoy what I do :)."],
    "type": "employee"
},
{
    "imageSmall": ["images/employee_jpgs/employees_barbra_80x80.jpg"],
    "imageBig": ["images/employee_jpgs/employees_barbra_150x150.jpg"],
    "name": ["Barbra Gago"],
    "quotes": ["The best part about working at tibbr is how dynamic the environment is, there's a lot of flexibility and freedom to execute on new ideas. Because everyone is so talented, there is a ton of trust and support coming from managers and team members-we all count on each other to do the best possible job!"],
    "type": "employee"
},
```

the same continues but there are 3 types
1-employee
2-twitter
3-social

Now my problem is I want get these json data randomly and append to my div element
I used following code

```
function(args){
 var me=this;
 $.getJSON(args.json,function(data) { 
 me.set(args);
 $.each(data, function(i){
    var id="randomizr_item_" + i;
    var temp= $('<div id='+ id +' class="randomizr-grid-items"><img src="'+ this.imageSmall[0]  +'" /></div>');
    me.config.container.append(temp);
    this.target=$(temp);
});
```

I know how to generate single random entry using following code

```
entry = data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)];
```

which generates single random entry.

Plz help me how to get json data randomly from above json file and append to div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an array of random unique numbers like following:

```
function generateRandom(min, max) {
    var arr = [];
    while(arr.length < 5){
      var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
          found=false;
      for(var i=0;i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] == randNum){found=true;break}
      }
      if(!found)arr[arr.length] = randNum;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Then you need to loop over data like following:

Here I am looping over unique array, not on `data` and using value of array as index to `data`.

```
var orders = generateRandom(0, data.length-1);

$.each(orders, function(index, value){
    var id="randomizr_item_" + i;
    var temp= $('<div id='+ id +' class="randomizr-grid-items"><img src="'+ data[value].imageSmall[0]  +'" /></div>');
    me.config.container.append(temp);
    this.target=$(temp);
});
```

**[A simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/121/)**

Comment: Worst random generation ever.

Comment: Each loop you are forgetting the fact that you already chose an element. If the element you *decide* to forget is chosen again then you are just wasting time. Make it *remember* and it will be better.

Comment: Alexander- can u give me a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You should create a 'Deck' and fill it with the json data.

Once the Deck is filled, loop through it while it has elements, like this:

```
while(deck.length > 0) {
 var random_index = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length);
 var item = deck[random_index];
 // do stuff with item
 deck = jQuery.removeFromArray(random_index, deck);
}
```

Add this code to the top of your js file:

```
jQuery.removeFromArray = function(value, arr) {
    return jQuery.grep(arr, function(elem, index) {
        return elem !== value;
    });
};
```